24.04: Journal too large despite SystemMaxUse and SystemKeepFree
I have /var/log on a separate device of just 100MBs. I am managing the disk space for normal logs via logrotate, for journald I was trying to do this through /etc/systemd/journald.conf. It's not working, though:
[Journal]
SystemMaxUse=50M
SystemKeepFree=16000M
RuntimeMaxUse=40M

disk space used exceeds 50M by more than 100%:
# journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 117.1M in the file system.

Over the last weeks, the journal has now grown to a state where journald can't fix the situation on its own:
# journalctl -b --no-pager _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-journald.service
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Collecting audit messages is disabled.
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Journal started
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/214b8447bbfe4abba739f97a142d1916) is 5.0M, max 40.0M, 35.0M free.
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/214b8447bbfe4abba739f97a142d1916) is 5.0M, max 40.0M, 35.0M free.
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: File /var/log/journal/214b8447bbfe4abba739f97a142d1916/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Failed to open system journal: No space left on device
Dec 07 07:43:44 gateway systemd-journald[551]: Time jumped backwards, rotating.

I know there are several ways now to fix the situation on the spot, including vacuuming or just deleting the journal files. I could possibly also resolve the situation perpetually by setting up a daily cron job to do vacuuming. I don't want to resort to such bandaid just yet, however, but would like to understand how to configure journald properly:
What I would need to set in the config to effectively limit journald to 50M. The settings I have are obviously not good enough, although I tried much more than just "SystemMaxUse" after googling the issue.
In case somebody should need this:
/var/log/journal/214b8447bbfe4abba739f97a142d1916# ls -al
total 114328
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 root systemd-journal    1860 Dec  7 07:43 .
drwxr-sr-x+ 3 root systemd-journal      60 Nov 16 03:03 ..
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 03:00 system@0006271233ac2b8b-2c300f936af5b75b.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 07:25 system@00062715df7cccd9-c16ff05ba984cf9b.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 07:40 system@0006271634bd7e9e-18cded3387f553a0.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 03:00 system@00062726a7d55fa5-17693779bae8cc69.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 19 03:00 system@0006273ac6005e8d-69111cf322e10933.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 20 03:00 system@0006274e8be785cd-17d97875c98b65f7.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 21 03:00 system@00062762ac443a42-623bd883ddecbdb7.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 22 03:00 system@00062776c8c06547-f3d39af933829ceb.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 03:00 system@0006278ae6b04b38-cc34cb417dd2b8b2.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 12:46 system@000627930cd19b15-1be2952981db5337.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 03:00 system@0006279f048caf82-2276beef9b6f39dc.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 17:51 system@000627ab6d321f64-282a6e289a66a7fa.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 18:16 system@000627abc68d27c8-2fc70e6a8d3e9a8f.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 25 03:00 system@000627b32262fde2-b0c78ff78982c74f.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 26 03:00 system@000627c796c95369-378f2788d71cea58.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 27 03:00 system@000627db5e0d802f-bbe930c7b7cc2884.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 28 03:00 system@000627ef7be287d5-8e2b9994cb7b6fea.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 29 03:00 system@0006280399bb3872-704e53a8132f2b75.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 30 03:00 system@00062817b779bdf5-a36052b5209bae0e.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  1 03:00 system@0006282bd56fc255-1fd7d2f5a7e45aee.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  2 03:00 system@0006283ff3403b50-cbd5954849bd0b27.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  3 03:00 system@000628541124c688-858ed8600252ae1b.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  4 03:00 system@000628682eed3bd5-4f2d3a6ad72bed22.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 03:00 system@0006287c4cc54ec6-f0aa39b4dcb0e977.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  6 03:00 system@000628906a9c2ebf-4f6c9b3175325aab.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  7 03:00 system@000628a4defae147-94ec2f3c787a7721.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  7 03:00 system@000628a873eb7548-c4bc8caa11cf616b.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 21 11:08 system@0be54a54a70f4a7f93a8f5acc242ebea-00000000000093b6-00062762ac42d88f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 21 23:01 system@0be54a54a70f4a7f93a8f5acc242ebea-0000000000009ee0-0006276971097c35.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 10:01 system@2800bad1984a4a5e8249fcdde2f73602-000000000000c71b-0006278ae6ab4e5b.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  2 11:14 system@2c862e9d86b849d29146af36c321215d-000000000001c4b3-0006283ff33cee95.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  2 22:59 system@2c862e9d86b849d29146af36c321215d-000000000001cfe1-00062846cfea0813.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  1 11:06 system@2f60706790f242a0b6a6da5ceb8f025d-000000000001aae8-0006282bd566a38b.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  1 23:00 system@2f60706790f242a0b6a6da5ceb8f025d-000000000001b61b-00062832957f4728.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 11:16 system@33c921c8f4de430ea952d48bf15537dc-000000000000e92e-0006279f04899b3d.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 16 11:53 system@34a36265677946739ad13c76a32a37c0-0000000000000324-000626fe15c43810.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 00:30 system@34a36265677946739ad13c76a32a37c0-0000000000000e2f-000627057df44c2e.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 27 11:08 system@4ab06f2235204f0386ea0bc2898ec2ee-000000000001439e-000627db5e081e2f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 27 23:01 system@4ab06f2235204f0386ea0bc2898ec2ee-0000000000014ecd-000627e22412a6c6.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 25 00:51 system@526c4b04d01842f6908c840134f0f250-000000000001015f-000627abc68c4307.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 29 11:15 system@6639dc2057204f7592f3d4d42752fdd5-0000000000017770-0006280399b629d0.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 29 23:00 system@6639dc2057204f7592f3d4d42752fdd5-000000000001829d-0006280a78ce6aad.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 11:16 system@68cb813ae84d434abe4d596be08c3ae2-000000000002136b-0006287c4cc4b07a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 22:36 system@68cb813ae84d434abe4d596be08c3ae2-0000000000021e9c-000628832f6f7de2.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 10:45 system@6eacf586b52643d89f3f86e64e47e6a7-00000000000041d9-00062726a7d3464f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 19:21 system@6eacf586b52643d89f3f86e64e47e6a7-0000000000004d23-0006272cc541614e.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 26 11:32 system@8155b240de694d6fbc59a68564175bcd-00000000000129ec-000627c796c751ea.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 26 23:10 system@8155b240de694d6fbc59a68564175bcd-0000000000013519-000627ce5d484c33.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 20 10:50 system@84f1d1a7c8ff459abe0e8a3a704b1c19-0000000000007931-0006274e8be6d36a.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 20 22:20 system@84f1d1a7c8ff459abe0e8a3a704b1c19-0000000000008484-0006275512d5ec6c.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 28 11:17 system@85eb7fbdb0d04be08073188bffea4930-0000000000015d65-000627ef7bdd0835.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 28 22:45 system@85eb7fbdb0d04be08073188bffea4930-000000000001689b-000627f6621e8de9.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 25 11:10 system@99beef625c3b4e6a8b5d3eebe11be6df-0000000000011047-000627b32261d082.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 25 23:04 system@99beef625c3b4e6a8b5d3eebe11be6df-0000000000011b75-000627b9ef8d1929.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 30 11:09 system@a3c8c06e89b2478ab0f3df167225b09f-000000000001911f-00062817b77866dc.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 30 23:06 system@a3c8c06e89b2478ab0f3df167225b09f-0000000000019c51-0006281e82633a79.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  4 11:08 system@add9a48fc2484c70b7800e6194ef9a19-000000000001f826-000628682ee7fc64.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  4 21:46 system@add9a48fc2484c70b7800e6194ef9a19-0000000000020354-0006286ef4f5ac34.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 15:45 system@b632697d6df94e92aeebee7ef73fbe31-0000000000002ae6-0006271634bc89ac.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 02:47 system@b632697d6df94e92aeebee7ef73fbe31-000000000000366c-0006271cd8440ae2.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 20:51 system@bff377771a69448a9c117996ba47fc03-000000000000d7ee-000627930cd0539e.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 19 11:39 system@caf42cb256b1425d9db06ff8d610963a-0000000000005f82-0006273ac5fbbb1b.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 19 23:08 system@caf42cb256b1425d9db06ff8d610963a-0000000000006aae-00062741a42f81de.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  3 11:10 system@e1b62490f888489e8926c2642953ca15-000000000001de78-00062854112238fa.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  3 23:04 system@e1b62490f888489e8926c2642953ca15-000000000001e9aa-0006285adf7bf191.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 22 11:17 system@eb2ba0d5270841d0963aa38bb64046e6-000000000000ad66-00062776c8bf9cfd.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 22 22:59 system@eb2ba0d5270841d0963aa38bb64046e6-000000000000b89a-0006277daf11f403.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  6 11:16 system@f5586191ee47484984f06cff09ae57a4-0000000000022da2-000628906a975db2.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  6 23:09 system@f5586191ee47484984f06cff09ae57a4-00000000000238d6-000628974d44e727.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 22:36 user-1000.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 07:25 user-1000@00062715e05530cd-fd993a69ef188915.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 07:40 user-1000@0006271afa980002-15f798cd31aa41b9.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 19 03:00 user-1000@00062741a42f8c49-3172cbf85f2dcc81.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 12:46 user-1000@00062799d1ac0452-93793be008e3f4a8.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 12:46 user-1000@000627a5e72d9026-0d5ce59725adff23.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 17:51 user-1000@000627ab6de7b9d8-7732927473709003.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 24 18:16 user-1000@000627abc74af294-f1c22a210bf7b5e9.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 03:00 user-1000@000628832f6f84e7-ae26d45e2a43b969.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 23 10:01 user-1000@2800bad1984a4a5e8249fcdde2f73602-000000000000cf1f-0006278eb5f999e1.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 25 00:51 user-1000@526c4b04d01842f6908c840134f0f250-0000000000010564-000627abc74af167.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  5 22:36 user-1000@68cb813ae84d434abe4d596be08c3ae2-0000000000022781-0006288b7ef0c60c.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 10:45 user-1000@6eacf586b52643d89f3f86e64e47e6a7-000000000000498e-0006272a2da82765.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 19:21 user-1000@6eacf586b52643d89f3f86e64e47e6a7-0000000000005134-0006272ee7302306.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 26 23:10 user-1000@8155b240de694d6fbc59a68564175bcd-0000000000013f00-000627d7e1d3892c.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 20 10:50 user-1000@84f1d1a7c8ff459abe0e8a3a704b1c19-0000000000008247-0006275358fcbd3f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 20 22:20 user-1000@84f1d1a7c8ff459abe0e8a3a704b1c19-00000000000088b8-0006275911806f5f.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 28 22:45 user-1000@85eb7fbdb0d04be08073188bffea4930-0000000000016b5a-000627f8e557f9d7.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Dec  4 21:46 user-1000@add9a48fc2484c70b7800e6194ef9a19-000000000002061d-0006287090f27a09.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 17 15:45 user-1000@b632697d6df94e92aeebee7ef73fbe31-0000000000003373-0006271afa97ff34.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 18 02:47 user-1000@b632697d6df94e92aeebee7ef73fbe31-000000000000382c-0006271dfec492e1.journal
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 6553600 Nov 19 23:08 user-1000@caf42cb256b1425d9db06ff8d610963a-0000000000006e59-0006274507049591.journal

Thanks.
